# How to keep the content of the BuildRoot?

Tags: rpm

The good old rpm while building package in steps simply kept the content of the BuildRoot -- it was very useful for me, because if some piece of software was difficult to create, I could check BuildRoot if everything is OK.

Now, with all "improved" rpm -- the content of BuildRoot is deleted automatically, so I cannot really dive into it (installing step is not that long).

One hack I know of would be adding some kind of sleep at the end of install stage to rpm spec. But this is ugly.

So -- **QUESTION** -- how to keep the content of BuildRoot in nice way -- in other words, how to disable auto delete once and for good?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using `rpmbuild -bi` in testing, so that the you get everything built up through the `%install` phase? That should show you what's going on without automatically cleaning afterwards.

Then when you're satisfied, build as normal.

Comment: Thank you. This is the least intrusive approach and it works.

Answer (score 9):

Just add

```
    %define __spec_install_pre /bin/true
```

on top of the `.spec` file

Comment: It works for me in RHEL/CentOS 7.

Comment: This works in Fedora 27.

Comment: And if someone is building from `.src.rpm`, there is a way to do this via CLI:
`rpmbuild --define '__spec_install_pre /bin/true' --rebuild *.src.rpm`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a dummy `%clean` to the spec file. Something like:

```
%clean
echo NOOP
```

Comment: doesn't work, because BUILDROOT is deleted at the beginning of %install - it is part of the initialization of %install.

Comment: If the goal is to keep buildroot after the build, for investigation, then it does work.

Answer (score 0):

This *is* annoying, I agree. If you don't mind modifying your rpm, I suggest going into the rpm source and finding out where the BuildRoot is deleted, disable that line (it is probably only one line), and recompile. The other thing I would suggest is filing a wishlist bug to restore the old behaviour, which I believe was configurable.

Question: in what version of rpm did this behavior change?

Comment: I don't know about the version, but change in official rpm would be tough: http://lists.rpm.org/pipermail/rpm-list/2008-December/000040.html The explanation indicates that idelogy play a huge role. Patching rpm would be possible though, thank you for the hint. Maybe I would manage revert automatic BuildRoot creating too.

Comment: @macias: I looked at the rpm sources on Debian (4.9.0-2), but didn't find out anything useful. However, even if the developers are not willing to change it, I expect they are willing to tell you how to do it for yourself.

Comment: luckily the -bi switch works for **this** case, so I skip patching if I can -- the software list with regressions are getting longer anyway.